# Reduce sql azure replication cost

Tags: azure-sql-database

Here is the situation, we have intense requests demands on our sql azure database, so we decided to replicate the database, one for read (sql queries) and one for writing (updates) given that we have to move to premium service so the database cost in creases from pretty 300 dollars to 2000 dollars and that affect dramatically the project rentability, so is there any other solutions to optimise that cost

Thank you

Comment: why can't You scale up database ,instead of replicating.Replication main motto is ,availabilty in case of disaster.Try Scaling up the database and evaluate which tier fits you in.

Answer (score 0):

Are any of these options viable for you?

- Running traditional SQL in an Azure VM (not limited to Azure SQL DTU model)
- Using a message queue to move writes to an eventual consistent model using competing consumers
- Create de-normalized/pre-computed tables (i.e. SELECT INTO) for the read operations during low-use times
- Use materialized and/or indexed views for reads (reduced CPU/DTU usage)
- Push data into Azure Table or DocumentDB for reads

Just ideas, but I feel your pain. The DTU thing is both a blessing and a curse.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for suggesions, we have to test those options whether they hurt performance and availability or not. We are even thinking to move to MySQL server cluster but we can't estimate that since we don't know how to evaluate this with the pricinig calculator